# Reporting Services Horizintal calendar with monthly and weekly sum

Tags: reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I want to create a report that represents a horizonal calendar by the specified month. Data cells of matrix contains the work hours of the employees.

The problems just follow:

- need to sum the monthly hours of the employee at the beginning of the line
- also need to sum the week hours of the hours and insert a column after Sunday weekday with sum hours

[image: calendar representation]

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE!

The answer below solve my main problem, the only problem is that, in the first data row is empty in all case.
I think the empty row is displayed because not all days contain working hours and SSRS cannot group empty days, but i do not know what expression is the solution.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? The solution lies in your SQL. Do some research on how to use the pivot statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some sort of week number to group by...

Add a Row group by Employee, ....looks like this is already done.

For column groups, start with a group by date, then add a parent group with a header (right click your date group Add Parent, in the dialogue select your week number as the field to group on and select the include header option).
Then add a total total group to the week number group to get your overall totals.

If you need a more detailed answer let me know and provide some sample data to work with.

Comment: I am very appreciate your help.
I want to ask detailed answer, because I have a beginner skills in SSRS.

Comment: You'll need to provide some sample data to work from as it in your database.

Comment: What sample data do you want exactly? Report data is only the work hours and employee names.

Comment: I have a dynamic datasource and the datamodel has the following properties: EmployeeName, WorkDayHours, WeekHours, DayName, DayNumber, WeekNumber

Comment: It looks like, your guidance helped me a lot. My only problem is that there is an empty row in the the data range. Can you help with that? This is because not all of the day has work hours.

Comment: Update your question to show your dataset ersults and what you are currently getting and I'll see what I can do

Comment: It looks like you have a NULL or empty value in the EmployeeName column for one for more rows. Post the actual output from your dataset query if you can't fix it.